# Patient Special Handling in FHIR 4

Tags: hl7-fhir

Is there a good place to store patient privacy indicators? (e.g. do not call, special handling of mailings, password protected account, special claims handling, etc...) I am considering using Basic to capture this.  The resource will need to contain periods for each classification.

Comment: Are those really patient properties or user properties?  For example, a pediatric patient probably don't have those, but their parents, who would have an account and be able to access their kid's chart, would.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of information would typically be captured as Observations - as they're all point-in-time assertions.  The same approach is used for things like food preferences, location of valuables, etc.  For tags that control access to a record, also look at Resource.meta.security

Comment: Regarding the comment I posted on the main question - would Observation actually work for non-patient properties?  These actually feel like user properties, not patient properties (e.g. for the pediatric scenarios).

Comment: Observations can have a subject of a Patient, Practitioner, RelatedPerson, Organization, Location - or any resource at all.  A 'user' in FHIR would generally be represented as Patient, Practitioner or RelatedPerson.

Answer (score 0):

We've faced a similar problem in the implementation of Swedish national medications list - and ended up with a similar solution, a [Basic resource](https://simplifier.net/guide/swedishnationalmedicationlist/DataLock). At the end of the day it's this or extensions on Patient.